# Splitting lists into to different lists

Tags: python, list

I have a list:

```py
list =  [['X', 'Y'], 'A', 1, 2, 3]
```

That I want to split into:

```py
new_list = [['X','A', 1, 2, 3] , ['Y', 'A', 1, 2, 3]]
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll suggest a more concise approach that uses iterable unpacking -- IMO it's cleaner than using list slices.

We take the first element of `lst` and separate it from the rest of the list. Then, we use a list comprehension to create a new list for every element in the original sublist of `lst`:

```py
lst = [['X', 'Y'], 'A', 1, 2, 3]
fst, *rest = lst

[[elem, *rest] for elem in fst]
```

This outputs:

```py
[['X', 'A', 1, 2, 3], ['Y', 'A', 1, 2, 3]]
```

Comment: Agreed, this is cleaner than slicing. Nice

Comment: Yeah, that was clean, thanks

Comment: I have one question though. If i have a list with for exampel, [[['X', 'Y'], 'A', 1, 2, 3],[[Q', 'B'], 'A', 1, 2, 3]]. Would this method work?

Comment: @abh Yes, you would wrap the above code into another for loop or comprehension. Something like `[[elem, *rest] for elem, *rest in lst]`

Comment: I tried, but didn't really get it... How would you go about doing it? :)

Answer (score 2):

Sure, take off the first element to create an outer loop, and then loop over the rest of the list to build the sub-lists:

```py
lst = [['X', 'Y'], 'A', 1, 2, 3]

new_list = []

for item in lst[0]:
    sub = [item]
    for sub_item in lst[1:]:
        sub.append(sub_item)
    new_list.append(sub)
```

Or, as a comprehension:

```py
new_list = [[item, *lst[1:]] for item in lst[0]]
```

Where the `*lst[1:]` will unpack the slice into the newly created list.

Borrowing that idea for the imperative for-loop:

```py
new_list = []

for item in lst[0]:
    sub = [item, *lst[1:]]
    new_list.append(sub)
```

Answer (score 0):

This probably not the best aproach but it works

```py
l = [['X', 'Y'], 'A', 1, 2, 3]

new_list = []
to_append = []
for item in l:
    if isinstance(item, list):
        new_list.append(item)
        continue

    to_append.append(item)

new_list.append(to_append)
print(new_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the code below returns exactly what you want.

```py
list =  [['X', 'Y'], 'A', 1, 2, 3]
new_list = []

for i, item in enumerate(list[0]):
    new_list.append([item] + list[1:])

print(new_list)
```